# How to avoid for loops for multiplication of all permutations of a matrix?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, simplification

I have the following code:

```
  N=8;
  K=10;
  a=zeros(1,N^(K-1));
  b=zeros(1,N^(K-1));

  for ii=1:K
    p0{ii}=rand(1,N);
    p1{ii}=rand(1,N);
  end

  k=1;
  for j1=1:N
    for j3=1:N
      for j4=1:N
        for j5=1:N
          for j6=1:N
            for j7=1:N
              for j8=1:N
                for j9=1:N
                  for j10=1:N
                    a(k)=p0{1}(j1)*p0{3}(j3)*p0{4}(j4)*p0{5}(j5)*p0{6}(j6)*p0{7}(j7)*p0{8}(j8)*p0{9}(j9)*p0{10}(j10);
                    b(k)=p1{1}(j1)*p1{3}(j3)*p1{4}(j4)*p1{5}(j5)*p1{6}(j6)*p1{7}(j7)*p1{8}(j8)*p1{9}(j9)*p1{10}(j10);
                    k=k+1;
                  end
                end
              end
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
    end
```

I am not able to evaluate this code for `N=8`, because it takes a lot of time. `p0` and `p1` are matrices of size `KxN`. The nested for loop is omiting one row of `p0` and `p1`, here the second row corresponding to the index `j2`. The rest of the matrix elements are multiplied with each other. So in total there are `N^(K-1)` multiplications in order to obtain the vectors `a` and `b`.

> Is there any way to do this thing without using for loops or at least in some reasonable time?

Comment: Is it important that `p0` and `p1` are cells?

Comment: @Irreducible yes and no. In the general yes, as it may be the case that N is actually N1, N2,.. etc. which are different for each loop and no because most of the case N is fixed and the cells can be treated as matrix of size K by N.

Comment: Lets assume the N is fixed, than it looks like you want to do choose permutations of K elements taken from the vector (1:N), with repetitions. (representing the rows of interest to calculate your product)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you just multiply each element from each `p0` (or `p1`) cell with each other. Using some magic from [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) and [element-wise multiplication](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html), this can simplified to one loop.

Let's have a look at the following code:

```matlab
N = 3;
K = 10;

for ii = 1:K
  p0{ii} = rand(1, N);
  p1{ii} = rand(1, N);
end  

a = zeros(1, N^(K-1));
b = zeros(1, N^(K-1));

%for ii = 1:K
%  p0{ii} = rand(1, randi(N));
%  p1{ii} = rand(1, randi(N));
%end

tic;
k = 1;
for j1 = 1:N
  for j3 = 1:N
    for j4 = 1:N
      for j5 = 1:N
        for j6 = 1:N
          for j7 = 1:N
            for j8 = 1:N
              for j9 = 1:N
                for j10 = 1:N
                  a(k) = p0{1}(j1)*p0{3}(j3)*p0{4}(j4)*p0{5}(j5)*p0{6}(j6)*p0{7}(j7)*p0{8}(j8)*p0{9}(j9)*p0{10}(j10);
                  b(k) = p1{1}(j1)*p1{3}(j3)*p1{4}(j4)*p1{5}(j5)*p1{6}(j6)*p1{7}(j7)*p1{8}(j8)*p1{9}(j9)*p1{10}(j10);
                  k = k+1;
                end
              end
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
toc;

tic;
aa = p0{1};
bb = p1{1};
% For MATLAB versions R2016 and newer:
for jj = 3:K
  aa = reshape(aa .* p0{jj}.', 1, numel(aa) .* numel(p0{jj}));
  bb = reshape(bb .* p1{jj}.', 1, numel(bb) .* numel(p1{jj}));
end
% For MATLAB versions before R2016b: 
%for jj = 3:K
%  aa = reshape(bsxfun(@times, aa, p0{jj}.'), 1, numel(aa) .* numel(p0{jj}));
%  bb = reshape(bsxfun(@times, bb, p1{jj}.'), 1, numel(bb) .* numel(p1{jj}));
%end
toc;

numel(find(aa ~= a))
numel(find(bb ~= b))
```

The output:

```
Elapsed time is 2.39744 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.00070405 seconds.
ans = 0
ans = 0
```

It seems, `a` and `aa` as well as `b` and `bb` are actually equal, and the proposed solution is much faster. I tested `N = 8` just for my solution:

```
Elapsed time is 1.54249 seconds.
```

If you replace the initialization of `p0` and `p1` by uncommenting the corresponding lines, you'll see my solution also allows for varying lengths for each `p0` (or `p1`) cell. Notice: This doesn't work for your initial solution due to the hardcoding, so comparisons can't be made here.

Also, please note, that `jj = 3:N` is hardcoded here, too. If other parts should be omitted instead, this has to be modified accordingly!

Hope that helps!

Comment: sorry. but it seems that this code doesnt work. I just copied and pasted. here is what i got:  Error using  .* 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören Please always give a full stack trace, when mentioning possible errors. Nevertheless, I guess it's `numel(aa) * numel(p0{jj})` and the other line. Change it to `numel(aa) .* numel(p0{jj})` to explicitly get element-wise multiplication. If that's not the error, please provide the full stack trace as mentioned.

Comment: no. I also thought so. but it is not the problem. I am wondering how were you able to run this code? so numel(aa) * numel(p0{jj}) is not a problem. it gives 9. I had a look at this part aa .* p0{jj}.'  and it is actually the part which gives an error. I tried to correct it as follows: (aa .* p0{jj}).'  it is then working but giving only 3 element. So reshape cannot make a 1,9 vector from a 3 by 1 and reshape crashes.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören Do you use an older version of MATLAB, specifically any version before R1026b? In that version, [implicit expansion](https://nhigham.com/2016/09/20/implicit-expansion-matlab-r2016b/) was introduced, which allows several operations on arrays. I will try to set up a version using [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), which explicitly allows these operations.

Comment: older is relative. for me matlab 2015a is very new version. so I think you call all the versions below 2019 old?:)

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören I added a version using `bsxfun`. Hopefully, this will resolve any issues regarding implicit expansion, that occur with MATLAB versions older than R2016b.

Comment: okay. this guy seems to be working. these guys numel(find(aa != a))
numel(find(bb != b)) need to be numel(find(aa ~= a))
numel(find(bb ~= b)). btw. I am wondering, do you have speed comparison between the two versions? I have no matlab over 2016, else I could do it by myself.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören Implicit expansion and using `bsxfun` are comparably fast. I don't see significant variations between those two versions. Does the modified code now work for you?

Comment: I have a little question if you dont mind. your method is working pretty well. However if I have $K> 10$ and $N=8$ then RAM is not enough. Is there any easy solution to this problem?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören Just to clarify: Do you get `out of memory` errors just for my solution or also for your own code? I can't see any obvious, additional memory usage in my code. In general: If matrices are big to fit into memory, you need more RAM or you need to somehow split your calculations.

Comment: out of memory yes. I think its the same for both codes. the size of a and b are exp. increasing. so for K=11 and N=8 we have two vectors of length 11^8=214358881, which are too much for my 32 GB ram. I am actually interested in 'pe' as follows: pm=sum(b(a>=b)); pf=sum(a(a<b)); pe=0.5*(pf+pm);

Comment: I could do it in my code for example I could calculate a until 1 million length. then calculate some some portion of pe and do it many times without memory problems. But I dont know how one could do this with your code..